# Create a vector with macro iterator syntax

Tags: rust, static, mutable, rust-proc-macros

How can I create a new vector with the iterator Rust macro syntax?

I am trying this:

```
unsafe { 
    MUT_STATIC_VAR = vec![
       #(#my_outher_vector_data)*,
    ];
}
```

Full explanation: I am trying to reasign data that I write in one mut static var of type: Vec when the macro it's spanded at compile time. When I try to retrieve the data at runtime, the global it's empty, so I am rewiring the data that I want in `main()`.

Recap. I am just want to assign the content of one vector to another, but neither `array` or `Vec<T>` implements `ToTokens`.

Compiler error:

```
`main` function not found in crate `my_crate`
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. What is `ToTokens`? What does your entire macro look like? How does this relate to global variables? Can you show us the global variable and how you try to reassign it?

Comment: Please make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows exactly what you're writing and what errors you get.

Comment: Maybe the explanations of the answer below could clarify someone

Comment: The other Vec in the macro is `vec!["dog".to_string(), "cat".to_string(), "mouse".to_string()]` in the main fn as You need it. I took `String` as example for type `T`, as it was not specified in the question.

Comment: Is the code snippet part of your macro, or part of the code that you want your macro to generate?

Comment: Part of the macro

Comment: So... the purpse of this static variable is to cache some tokens so they can be used in multiple places? I think that is unnecessary.

Comment: They do not caché tokens. They caché other interesting data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize the content, `Iterators` are able to use macro `#(#...)*,` syntax.

```
let other_as_iter = my_outher_vector_data.iter();


quote {
    unsafe { 
        MUT_STATIC_VAR = vec![
           #(#other_as_iter)*,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Despite the complexity of the initialization, the macro can't process dynamic data at runtime…

Comment: This only works for iterators with a single value. For more than one value, a comma needs to be added after each element: `#(#other_as_iter,)*`

Answer (score -1):

I think `lazy_static` should do the job:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
use std::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    static ref MUT_STATIC_VAR: Mutex<Vec<String>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
}

fn other_vec(v: Vec<String>) {
    let mut r = MUT_STATIC_VAR.lock().unwrap();
    r.extend_from_slice(v.as_slice());
}

fn main() {
    other_vec(vec!["dog".to_string(), "cat".to_string(), "mouse".to_string()]);
}
```

…or draining the other vec after initializing `MUT_STATIC_VAR`:

```
fn other_vec(v: &mut Vec<String>) {
    let mut r = MUT_STATIC_VAR.lock().unwrap();
    r.extend_from_slice(v.drain(..).as_slice());
}

fn main() {
    other_vec(&mut vec!["dog".to_string(), "cat".to_string(), "mouse".to_string()]);
}
```

…or `my_other_vector_data` wrapped in `other_vec!` macro:
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=649df19b825552f3b40f9154e58412ce)

```
macro_rules! other_vec {
    () => {
        vec!["dog", "cat", "mouse"] // my_other_vector_data here
    };
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243031/discussion-on-answer-by-kaplan-create-a-vector-with-macro-iterator-syntax).